# Simple jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, forms

So I have a basic form

```
<div id="webForm_Contact">
    <form action="">
        <label for="form_fName"> Full name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="form_fName"><br />
        <label for="form_email" > Email: </label>
        <input type="text" id="form_email"><br />
        <label for="form_phone"> Phone </label>
        <input type="text" id="form_phone"><br />
        <label for=""> Location: </label>
        <label for="form_radio_london"> London</label>
        <input type="radio" id="form_radio_london" value="London">
        <label for="form_radio_Toronto"> Toronto</label>
        <input type="radio" id="form_radio_Toronto" value="Toronto">        
        <label for="form_radio_other"> Other</label>
        <input type="radio" id="form_radio_other" value="Other">

        <!-- radio select here-->

            <div id="otherCity">
                <label for="form_otherCity"> Other City </label> 
                <input type="text" id="form_otherCity">
            </div>
            <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
</div>
```

and a simple jQuery::
Edit:: changed up the code a bit as I realized it was doing more then it needed it.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    if($("#form_radio_other").is(':checked') ){
        $("#otherCity").css("display:inline");
    }
    else{
        $("#otherCity").css("display:none");
    }   


});
```

What it's supposed to do, is if the "Other" radio button is clicked, unhide the "otherCity" div to allow for form input, other wise it needs to be hidden. What I'm not understanding is what's wrong. I'm not getting at browser related issues, just issues with the code it's self. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `name` attribute in your HTML (`<input type="radio" id="form_radio_other" value="Other">`) and your JQuery `css` function is invalid.

Change like this:

```
$('#form_radio_other').change(function(){
    if($("#form_radio_other").is(':checked') ){
       $("#otherCity").css("display","inline");
    }
    else{
        $("#otherCity").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EagAb/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your JavaScript to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio").change(function(){
        if($('#form_radio_other').is(':checked') ){
            $("#otherCity").css("display","inline");
        }
        else{
            $("#otherCity").css("display","none");
        }
    });
});
```

You should also add a `name` attribute with the same value to all your radio inputs, so they would actually work like radio buttons.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nWkhT/

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selectors are a bit messed up.

For example: `$('input:radio[name="form_radio_other"]').change...` is trying to select a radio with the name of form_radio_other, which doesn't exist. It should be `$('#form_radio_other')`.

`if($("form_radio_other")` isn't using a `.` or `#` to select what you're looking for either.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have selected just one radio button you have to use `name` attribute for each one

example: `<input type="radio" id="form_radio_london" value="London" name="myradiobuttongroup"/>`

Comment: Yea, just saw that and fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems here:

- The radio button names have to be the same, to put them in the same group
- JQuery CSS function is like `.css("attr", "value")`, not `.css("attr:value")`

---

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    if($("#form_radio_other").is(':checked') ){
        $("#otherCity").css("display", "inline");
    }
    else{
        $("#otherCity").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SEKj/5/)

Comment: Thanks! It's been a little bit since I've done some jQuery like this. I appreciate it.